# Emacs init pandoc setup

Tags: elisp, init-file

I am reading the [following](https://jgmaox.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/setup-markdown-in-emacs/) blog on setting up Emacs to use pandoc in such away that <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd> will open the document in my browser.

It says:

> Restart Emacs, and open a markdown file (for example test.md). Then select Options->Customize Emacs->Specific Option, enter `markdown-command`.
>
> enter `pandoc -f markdown -t html -s --mathjax --highlight-style=pygments` in the "Markdown Command" field and select "Apply and save".
>
> Then when you are editing your markdown file in Emacs, try <kbd>C-c C-c p</kbd>, the generated html will show up in your default browser.

What would be the Elisp entry in `.emacs`?

I am using Emacs 24.5.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "lsip entry", but maybe you are looking for this: `(setq markdown-command "pandoc -f markdown -t html -s --mathjax --highlight-style pygments")`?

Comment: This value should be saved in your `custom-file` you should see it there, and like @itsjeyd said, just use a setq, or even setq-default in your init.

Comment: @itsjeyd lisp is the programming language emacs uses and lsip is a typo.

Comment: Unfortunately the referred site has been removed. This is the page from archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20140215043007/http://jgmaox.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/setup-markdown-in-emacs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the Elisp code for setting `markdown-command` in your init-file:

```lisp
(setq markdown-command 
      "pandoc -f markdown -t html -s --mathjax --highlight-style=pygments")
```

You should check whether `markdown-command` is a [buffer-local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html). Do <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `markdown-command` <kbd>RET</kbd> and look for a line that says:

> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

If `markdown-command` is in fact buffer-local, you'll need to replace `setq` with `setq-default` in the code above.

---

To set up a custom key binding for the command that is bound to `C-c C-c p`, add the following code to your init-file:

```el
(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-p") #'command)
```

If you don't know what `C-c C-c p` is bound to, do <kbd>C-h k</kbd> <kbd>C-c C-c p</kbd> from a `markdown-mode` buffer to find out.

Comment: I have been out of town so I will give this a try either today or tomorrow.

Comment: The define-key line produces: `ne-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-p") (function command))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/dustin/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 915
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dustin/.emacs" "/home/dustin/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)` more stuff that is too long to fit

Comment: The define key part is superfluous I found and not needed. Also, an equal sign needs to be `-style=pygments`.

Comment: @dustin Added the missing `=`. No idea how it got lost! ;)